# Run a script on User login to Salesforce

Tags: authentication, salesforce

is there a way to run code (like S-CONTROL or APEX), or maybe popup a browser window (with my code) when the user logs in to Salesforce?

I am trying to capture the IP of the user for future validation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But, the platform autmatically logs all login activity. You can find this under:

```
Setup>Manage Users> Login History
```

**Update:** 
As pointed out by  Gavin Watkinson, you can also access this through [the API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm), or directly from Apex using SOQL.:

```
SELECT ApiType,ApiVersion,Application,Browser,ClientVersion,Id,LoginTime,LoginType,LoginUrl,Platform,SourceIp,Status,UserId 
FROM LoginHistory
```

Comment: LoginHistory can be accessed via the api

Comment: @GavinWatkinson Thanks, I was not aware of that, updated my answer.